# How to append one more item to repeated DOM without touching ng-repeat scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have list of items in ng-repeat

```
 <div layout="column"  
      class="md-whiteframe-1dp"   
      ng-repeat="item in  child.items track by item._id"  
      id={{item._id}}child>
 </div>
```

I want to append one more DOM element(one more itemToAppend) into list whithout touching child.items scope. I want just append the same look DOM element but with new data.

```
itemToAppend = {name: "itemToAppend", _id: "111"}
```

how to do it?
thanks in advance!:)

Comment: I don't understand your question.sorry.can you refrase it?

Comment: You have a searchable component and you wish to append something to UI component without changing parent dataset. Right? If yes, create a variable that is associated with UI instead of data. so assume `var dataset = [...]; var extraOptions = [...]; var uiDataset = dataset.concat(extraOptions)` and bind this variable with `ng-repeat`

Comment: You can add a button and on clicking make new entry

Comment: edited - no searchable component.

Comment: Sir don't use concat

Comment: use filter or push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to take another scope variable with empty array type and push the value on button click. Here I just have taken an text input and button for reference. But you can use the same in your way. Below is the code sample:

**HTML:**

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="sampleApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <input ng-model="newItem" type="text" />
      <button ng-click="add(newItem)">Add</button>
      <div ng-repeat="arr in child">
         {{arr}}
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="arr in tempchild track by $index">
       {{arr}}
     </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
(function(angular){
  var module = angular.module("sampleApp",[])
   .controller("myController", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.child = ['A', 'B' , 'C', 'D'];
    $scope.tempchild = [];
    $scope.add = function(item) {
      $scope.tempchild.push(item);
   };
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```

As you can see in above code, you will need to take another ng-repeat which iterates with the new $scope variable.

Full example can be found [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SXtDeCyUCCFwKNf1Qhbj?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I added a button which will help users to add items.

```
<input ng-model="newItem" type="text"></input>
        <button ng-click="add(newItem)">Add</button>
$scope.itemsInFolder = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
   var newItemsToAdd= $scope.itemsInFolder;
    $scope.add = function(item) {
        newItemsToAdd.push(item);
    };
```

Bind newItemsToAdd with ng-repeat

Comment: This is not helping actually. @Serhiy don't want to modify the scope.child variable.